# How to start stop Windows Services using Scripting Language like Vb Script or something?

Tags: windows, windows-services, vbscript

I Just want to manage Windows Services through Scripting languages( VB Script or Something ). Like Starting, stopping, Getting the status, Checking the dependencies etc. Please help with Code snippets or URL referances.

Answer (score 2):

Use this script to start a service:

```
'' Starts service 'strService' on computer named 'strComputer'
''
Sub StartService(strService, strComputer)
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
       & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colListOfServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Service Where Name ='" & strService & "'")
    For Each objService in colListOfServices
       objService.StartService
    Next
End Sub

'' Start Windows CardSpace service on local host:
StartService "idsvc", "."
```

Instead of `StartService`, you can use `StopService` to stop the service. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for other useful methods of `Win32_Service`.

Comment: This helped me lot. Thanks. But what to do if there are dependency services? will that too stop and start along ? also is there any "RestartService" like start and stop service ? Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please see the documentation of the StartService method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393660(VS.85).aspx). Any services on which the started service depends will be started automatically; any services that depend on the started service will not be started automatically. If you want to do the latter, you might use one of the script samples from http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/services/ (look for `Win32_DependentService`).